# Calibre Hangs on Xubuntu and Cinnamon, but not Ubuntu or XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, dropbox, cinnamon, calibre

This is a really strange problem that has just started.  It appears to happen to other python apps as well?  At the risk of misleading, I think it might have to do with moving my user files?

Firs, a bit of background.  I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.  I have my user files for both OS's(Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc.) on a shared ntfs partition.  I am mounting the shared partition in fstab with:

> UUID=xxxxxxxxxx   /media/SHARED/      ntfs-3g defaults,auto,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002 0 0

All was working fine, until somehow my Windows install got corrupted and it started putting user info in the wrong place, my only choice was a repair install to windows where I moved my user files from (S: is the SHARED partition) S:/chad to S:/Users/chad.

My first thought was a permissions issue, but I THINK I have that all sorted.

If I start Calibre on Ubuntu (Unity) it starts right up, but on  Cinnamon and Xubuntu sessions it will hang with very high hard drive usage at "Initializing user interface..".

The reason I think it might be related to moving my user files:  I had a similar issue with Dropbox.  If I changed the dropbox folder location in the dropbox app, Xubuntu would hang on opening the file browser with the same hard drive churning.  If I tried the same on Ubuntu, no problems.

I have tried uninstalling xubuntu, xfce and reinstalling, still same problem.  If I use the XFCE session things again work fine.

Where do I start to track down the error?

I tried to run calibre from the command line with debug option `calibre-debug --gui`.  The system completely hangs, and this is the error that keeps repeating:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  I found an answer (workaround?) to my calibre problem.

[From the Mobileread forums:](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3069847&postcount=6)

In terminal I entered:

```
calibre-debug -c "from calibre.gui2 import gprefs; gprefs['ui_style'] = 'calibre'"
```

That solved my problem.  I don't know what theme I had selected instead.  Maybe 'system'?